# JsonProcessingException thrown when trying writeValueAsString

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am new to Jackson. I am trying to just serialize a POJO (plain old java object) to JSON, and I keep getting a JsonProcessingException. I really do not understand why. Am I missing something?

```
public class Car {
    private String make;
    private String model;

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Car (String make, String model) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

and then elsewhere I have....

```
try {
    Car car = new Car("honda", "accord");        

    String serialized;

    // enable pretty formatting
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(car);

    System.out.println(serialized);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    System.out.println("Failed to serialize the object to JSON");
}
```

And my output is simply

```
Failed to serialize the object to JSON
```

What could possibly be going wrong here? I do not understand how this exception could be getting thrown.

Comment: share e.printStacktrace() output

Answer (score 3):

Check message in thrown exception in your catch block for more details:

```
e.getMessage()
```

or just flush stacktrace

```
e.printStacktrace()
```

Comment: Thank you. Guess I'm an idiot for not doing that before. Turns out I didn't have the right properties set on the `ObjectMapper` for visibility of what it detects. I am still not exactly sure why it wasn't working given that I have a public getter and setter, but I have something working now.